# Size of link_loops of a mesh circle is zero?

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

I have a mesh circle with 32 vertices and I am trying to get the edge loop of the circle (which is actually all vertices in sequence) with following code:

```
import bmesh
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)

bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
v_loops = bm.verts[0].link_loops
print(len(v_loops))

bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
e_loops = bm.edges[0].link_loops
print(len(e_loops))
```

However, at both places I get zero length of the edge loops. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I think `link_loops` function checks which face loops use the vertex/edge. From [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html) . For vertex: `Loops that use this vertex (read-only).` and for edge: `Loops connected to this edge, (read-only).` If you fill in a face with `F` then you get a value of 1. So it confirms my theory :)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Yes, that's right :) So how to get the edge loops connected to selected vert or edge of a non-manifold mesh. I checked the relevant threads on stackexchange and they seem to be talking about manifold meshes only.

Answer (score 0):

This will take an input list of edges of any length, take the first element of the list as the starting edge and "walk" around the edge loop of a non-manifold loop until it finds the first edge it started with and return a list of edges of the loop. The key is the `3`s.

`3` is the number of edges each vert is connected to. If it was `4` then it would be looking for manifold edges.

```
def get_loop(edges):

    edge_loop = []
    edge = edges[0] # edge at the start of the edge loop

    # get BMLoop that points to the right direction
    for loop in edge.link_loops:
        if len(loop.vert.link_edges) == 3:
            break

    first_edge = edge
    edge_loop.append(first_edge)
    next_edge = 0

    # stop when reach the end of the edge loop
    while len(loop.vert.link_edges) == 3 and next_edge != first_edge:

        # jump between BMLoops to the next BMLoop we need
        loop = loop.link_loop_prev.link_loop_radial_prev.link_loop_prev

        # following edge in the edge loop
        next_edge = loop.edge
        if next_edge != first_edge:
            edge_loop.append(next_edge)

    return edge_loop
```